# derivative in double integral

Tags: integration

can anyone help me by indications to do this derivativeintegral?

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t(\int^\ f(t-s,x-y)dy)ds
$$
for any test function $$ f = f(t,x) $$

I try the Leibniz's rule but it don't work for me.

regards

Comment: Why don't you show us how you applied the Leibniz integral rule so we can see why 'it don't work for' you?

Comment: The rule shows the deivation with respect to the first varible (t)  and the integral is in relation to the second variable (x). The problem here, the derivation and the integral are in relation to the first variable (t and s). I do not know how to do it in this case

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Liebniz's rule just give
$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t \int f(t-s,x-y)dsdy $$
$$= \int f(0,x-y) dy +\int_0^t\int \partial_t f(t-s,x-y)dyds $$

Comment: The rule shows the deivation with respect to the first varible (t) and the integral is in relation to the second variable (x). The problem here, the derivation and the integral are in relation to the first variable (t and s).

Comment: Yeah but Fubini's theorem says $$\int_0^t\int f(t-s,x-y)dyds = \int\int_0^t f(t-s,x-y)dsdy$$ so $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t\int f(t-s,x-y)dyds = \int \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t f(t-s,x-y)dsdy$$ so you can treat $x$ as constant.

Comment: OK.
so the derivative will be:
OK.
so the derivative will be
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t(\int^\ f(t-s,x-y)dy)ds = \int^\ ( f(0,x-y) - f(t,x-y))
$$
? it's correct ?

Comment: No it will be what's given in my answer. You will have to differentiate inside the integral and will only have one boundary term as the derivative of the other vanishes because it is not a function of $t$.

Comment: when I apply this on this function $$ f(t,x) = t + x $$ your answer don't work

Comment: It does work when you restrict $x$ to a compact set as $f$ will not be integrable on $[0,t]\times \mathbb{R}$